# Assignment of mapping in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-design

I have one mapping initialized before constructor.

```
mapping(address  => uint) TokenValsByAddress;
```

This mapping stores 10 addresses. 
After some operations , I got new mapping with same 10 addresses of `TokenValsByAddress` and new 2 address.

```
mapping(address  => uint) NewMapping;
```

Now I want to assign `NewMapping` to `TokenValsByAddress`.

I get an error when I do below assignment.

```
TokenValsByAddress = NewMapping;
```

> Error : Mappings can not be assigned to.

What should I do to update `TokenValsByAddress`  ?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot directly duplicate/copy a mapping in Solidity.

Mappings can grow to be extremely large and a copy operation could easily exceed the block gas limit.

See this answer for some more details about the gas limits:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/24519/3573

A strategy for duplicating a `mapping` is to keep an `array` of each key added to it. Then loop that `array` and assign the value from the old `mapping` to the new one.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.14;

contract Mapping {
    mapping(address => uint256) map;
    mapping(address => uint256) dupe;
    address[] keys;

    function add(uint256 value) {
        map[msg.sender] = value;
        keys.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function duplicate() {
        for(uint256 i; i < keys.length; i++) {
            dupe[keys[i]] = map[keys[i]];
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works, however it will pretty quickly hit the gas limit described above, plus some other limitations.

Looping a mapping in Solidity is generally considered an anti-pattern and should be avoided.