# Copying a mapping from Contract A to contract B

Tags: solidity

Is there any way at the moment that I can copy a mapping from one contract to the other?

```
mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

function importFrom(address _from) onlyOwner {
    Token s = Token(_from);
    balanceOf = s.balanceOf;
}
```

I want to allow this feature to enable smart contract upgrades. If this is not possible, I know that it is possible to use a delegatecall from one contract to the other; but then the problem is: how do I see the interface of the contract that is being called from the Ethereum wallet? I don't want to call directly the functions in that contract, but rather through the intermediary contract that then makes the call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no 'one-liner' in Solidity to copy/duplicate an entire mapping.

If you maintain a list of the keys of a mapping, it is possible to copy a *finite* amount of values from one mapping into another.

The amount of copies is finite as there is a limit on the amount of gas which can be consumed in a single block (`block.gasLimit`). Reading from and writing to contract storage costs gas.

The maximum `key => value` pairs in a mapping is `2**256`. From the [Ethereum Yellow Paper](http://yellowpaper.io/), a `SSET` operation costs `20,000` gas. Multiplying these gives `20000*(2**256) == 2.3e81` gas.

The most recent `block.gasLimit` when writing was`6.7e6`. This is dramatically lower than `2.3e81`, which was a purposeful underestimation of the true cost.

Duplicating a mapping of even a millionth (`1/1,000,000)` the maximum mapping size is an unreasonable amount of work for the EVM to do in a single transaction (or block).